# Edit text and add <br> tag in opencart footer content

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

A company dveloped a website for my cousin's skin care company. The site is developed in opencart. It has a footer in which I have to add a break tag and also edit copyright information but being new to opencart I am unable to find the content of the footer. If someone could help me to edit the footer content and also tell me where to locate the footer content in opencart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three files where that powered info is stored...
`catalog/controller/common/footer.php`

```
$data['powered'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_powered'), $this->config->get('config_name'), date('Y', time()));
```

`catalog/language/en-gb/common/footer.php`

```
$_['text_powered']      = 'Powered By <a href="http://www.opencart.com">OpenCart</a><br /> %s &copy; %s';
```

`catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/footer.twig`

```
<p>{{ powered }}</p>
```

You can edit your language file to get your info in the footer.

Comment: how can i do it using admin dashboard.

Comment: Use FTP to download files, edit it with notepad++ and upload them. You just only need to edit your language file

Comment: can u tell me where can i get the file on godaddy server.

Comment: If you do not know how to get the file via FTP, or how to use your server control panel, better to hire someone to do that. This will be more cheaper, than you'll create more issues...

Comment: i have made changes to the footer.twig file but the changes are not shown on the actual website. I have edited the file on my godaddy server but still it is not shown on the website. can you tell me what i am doing wrong